# Rest API Request Object as empty abstract or interface?

Tags: java, rest, api, interface, abstract

Trying to figure the best design for my api where all calls will take in a base form of a request. The response will be very similar for all the calls.
Some requests will inherit some properties while others will not. All the calls will funnel through the same service so the base request will be what the main service takes in.

I.e.

```
public Response mainServiceHandler(BaseRequest request)
```

My question is what are people's thoughts on an empty abstract BaseRequest vs an empty interface BaseRequest? Any advantages of one over other in terms of an api?  I thought an interface would always be the best manner since it is more flexible in design but wasn't sure if it applies in this case. Not too familiar with Marker interfaces but the little I read it didn't seem to be the best solution for this or does any implementation really makes much if a difference here.

Comment: Will it have state?

Comment: No it will be stateless

Comment: Both Abstract Class and Interface are used to enforce some sort of contract. What is that you want all implementations to have?